# const overloading and shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, c++14

Trying to get a better grasp on the rules surrounding const overloading. Consider the following code-

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
MyClass::MyClass() 
{
}
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

/*
void test_function(MyClass& test)
{
    cout << "ref to non const" << endl;
}
*/
void test_function(const MyClass& test)
{
    cout << "ref to const" << endl;
}
/*
void test_shared_ptr( shared_ptr<MyClass>& test)
{
    cout << "ref to non const shared ptr to non const" << endl;
}

void test_shared_ptr ( const shared_ptr<MyClass>& test)
{
    cout << "ref to const shared ptr to non const" << endl;
}
*/
void test_shared_ptr (const shared_ptr<const MyClass>& test)
{
    cout << "ref to const shared ptr to const" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass non_const_my_class;
    test_function(non_const_my_class);
    const MyClass const_my_class;
    test_function(const_my_class);

    shared_ptr<MyClass> non_const_ptr_to_non_const = make_shared<MyClass>                (MyClass());
    test_shared_ptr(non_const_ptr_to_non_const);

    const shared_ptr<MyClass> const_ptr_to_non_const = make_shared<MyClass>(MyClass());
    test_shared_ptr(const_ptr_to_non_const);

    const shared_ptr< const MyClass> const_ptr_to_const = make_shared< const MyClass>(MyClass());
    test_shared_ptr(const_ptr_to_const);

    int pause;
    cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```

With the methods commented out the output is :

```
ref to const
ref to const
ref to const shared ptr to const
ref to const shared ptr to const
ref to const shared ptr to const
```

This output is what I would expect, but I'm encountering a potential bug on some some code surrounding this type of const overloading. Really just looking to get some verification on the following statements:

1. It's always ok to pass non-const data into a function as a reference to const so long as that function does not attempt to violate the constness of its parameter. This would cause a compile error.
2. It's never ok, because it would cause a compile error, to pass const data into a function as a reference to non-const. This would be violating the constness of the data.

And as one final question-

In what circumstance could you possibly need code like the following? In my test code above, it was perfectly fine to pass non const data into a function as a const reference, so why should I ever need to do a `const_cast` like this?

```
void test_const_cast(const MyClass & test)
{
    //Do something
}

void test_const_cast( MyClass & test)
{
    test_const_cast(const_cast<MyClass const &>(test));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question seems to be that it is simply compiler dependent. It was OK to pass non const pointer to const data to a function taking a const pointer to const data as a parameter with the visual studio compiler, but not with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1: Close For C++98, even closer than for C++11. In C++11, when the Standard library is involved, a requirement is added that const member functions not introduce Data Races. See http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank. Outside the corner case of having an instance of a type that has a data-race-introducing const member function where the non-const overload does not, passing a mutable lvalue to a function taking reference-to-const is okay. *Even if* that function does violate the const-ness of its parameter (by using `const_cast<>()`).

Statement 2: It *is* okay to pass const data as a reference to non-const, *provided* the function does not actually change the object referred to by its parameter. This is the chief intended use-case for `const_cast<>()`.

Bonus Question: Code that uses `const_cast<>()` to *add* const is useful chiefly when the return value of the overloaded function is not void. For example, the standard library provides non-member `begin()` and `end()` functions for `std::vector<T /* technically more type paraeters here */>` such that the overload that takes `const vector<int>&`, for example returns `vector<int>::const_iterator` but the overload that takes `vector<int>&` returns `vector<int>::iterator`. If you wanted a `const_iterator` and not just an `iterator`, and didn't want the trouble of converting your `iterator` to a `const_iterator`, you might do that. And such is why C++17 introduces `as_const()` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const, to make it easier and without using the scary `const_cast<>()`.

Answer (score 0):

> It's always ok to pass non-const data into a function as a reference to const so long as that function does not attempt to violate the constness of its parameter. This would cause a compile error.

Not always. C++ does not like passing types that are templated with constants. Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

void test(const vector<const int> & b) { }

int main() {
  vector<int> a;
  test(a);
}
```

Here, `a` is a vector of `int` and `test` accepts a `const` vector of `const int`. The constraints on `test` are in essence a promise that it will modify neither `b` nor the elements in it; intuitively, it should place no constraint on `a` at all. Yet the code won't compile. In clang, for instance, you get this error:

```
test_template.cxx:11:3: error: no matching function for call to 'test'
  test(a);
  ^~~~
test_template.cxx:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'vector<int>' to 'const vector<const int>' for 1st argument
    void test(const vector<const int> & a) { }
     ^
```

Remove the `const` in front of `vector` and it does, in fact, compile (on clang, at least). So `const` doesn't work quite the way you have summarized.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The _template argument_ cannot be converted. [The object can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c391a03b99c56da). Your conclusions seem correct, but I think you have a typo. If you remove `const` in front `int`, you'll be correct.

Comment: In visual studio - "The c++ standard library forbids containers of const elements..."

Comment: @erip Remove `const` from the front of which `int`? I'm not sure why a change is necessary, but I agree with your clarification that the **template argument** cannot be converted, while the **object** can. I guess my notion of "data" is a little broader.

Comment: @LBaelish Odd, since clang accepts vectors containing `const int` all the time. Does it give a precise reference?